# Is it possible to register a listener to network activity in nanomsg?

Tags: nanomsg

I'm using **`nanomsg`** to handle my network coding (and it's very good btw!), but I am having trouble figuring out if there is a way to get notified when data is available to be received. The only way I can see is to continuously poll a socket for data using **`nn_poll()`**.  I abhor having a CPU core spin on network checking.

Is there a way to have a callback called when data can be received or do I have to run a while loop on a separate thread to fetch the incoming network data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

But if you want to avoid CPU core usage, you can increase `nn_poll` awaiting timeout.